# How can I display "-" as long as string length in textbox?

Tags: javascript, string, random

I have this list:

```js
let teams = [
  "real madrid",
  "barcelona",
  "milan",
  "inter",
  "juventus",
  "manchester united",
  "manchester city",
  "liverpool",
  "arsenal",
  "chelsea",
  "bayern munich",
];
```

I wrote code for choose random item from this list but I want display "-" as long as item length.

For example: choose **real madrid** ... I want this `- - - - - - - - - -` in the text box.

Comment: You forgot one `"-"` for the space between *Real* and *Madrid* — or you didn't? What have you tried? Please [edit] with a [mcve]. if still in doubt, read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a small RegExp that will match any non-space character `\S`, and replace it with a hyphen `-` (PS: `g` stands for *global* replace)

```js
const str = "Real Madrid";

const hyphenated = str.replace(/\S/g, "-");
console.log(hyphenated);
```

Happy [hangman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_(game))-ing!